# appending three byte arrays to each other

Tags: java, audio, arrays, wav, overwrite

i'm using this for a wav audio overwriting in audio recording, when user updates on the GUI the JSlider(progress) to a specific point and hits record we should perform the overwriting after the user hits stop this is how i do it :

```
if (progress.getValue() < progress.getMaximum()) {
     System.out.println("middle overwrite");
     byte[] firstdata = Arrays.copyOfRange(wavdata, 0, pos);
     byte[] remaindata = Arrays.copyOfRange(wavdata, firstdata.length + newwavdata.length, wavdata.length);
     wavdata = ByteArrayAppender(firstdata, newwavdata, remaindata);
     //System.out.println(remaindata.length);
     //System.out.println(firstdata.length);
     //wavdata=remaindata;
     }
InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(wavdata);
AudioInputStream ais1 = new AudioInputStream(input, WAVFormat(),wavdata.length/ WAVFormat().getFrameSize());

initiateAudioFunctions(ais1);

(...)

public byte[] ByteArrayAppender(byte[] firstData, byte[] newData, byte[] remainData) {

    byte[] editedByteArray = new byte[firstData.length + newData.length + remainData.length];
    System.arraycopy(firstData, 0, editedByteArray, 0, firstData.length);
    System.arraycopy(newData, 0, editedByteArray, firstData.length, newData.length);
    System.arraycopy(remainData, 0, editedByteArray, firstData.length + newData.length, remainData.length);

   return editedByteArray;

}
```

The problem is sometimes it works and sometimes not.
by not working i mean i get only noise, the copy is working correctly but the new data sometimes is copied as pure noise, and i'm wondering what possibly I could be doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you verify that ranges are correct? especially pos and newwavdata.length. Do you have 16 (or >8) Bit audio and your byte order gets mixed up?

Comment: pos is correct becuz the noise starts on the given pos and finishes on newwavdata.length, and   int sampleSizeInBits = 16; in the wav audio format.